# Use Excel VBA to replace characters inside txt file

Tags: excel, vba, txt

Good day everyone.

Background:
There is a .xlsx file that gets created with a way more advanced code (not mine) that I will describe soon-ish. For the file to be used it needs to be however saved as comma delimited csv (open->SaveAs->close files).

To get rid of this open->save->close I made a VBA code to do that for me. Works for me and some colleagues. BUT some have different excel settings so when they save as CSV file instead of "," -> ";" is getting used. This makes the csv unusable.

One way to solve that is to save as csv -> change file extension to .txt -> Ctrl+H replace all ";" with "," -> save and close the file -> change file extension to .csv.

I want to make sure that even the colleagues with different excel setting can create the csv file. Different macro (button) for the once with different settings, so no need to change the code for the one that works.

Changing the file format works with this line of code. Planning to also use it at the end of the Sub to go from .txt to .csv again.

Name "C:...\Test_csv_saved.csv" As "C:...\Test_csv_saved.txt"

Looked a bit on the web and think I can use this to replace ";" with ",".

sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "; ", ",")
Other ideas are welcome!

Still need a way to open that .txt file,(select all text maybe?), save it and close.

PS 1: The file has no decimals, so no need to worry about that.
PS 2: In the file there is a group of characters ...;;"ns=2;s=MAIN.test.text;;;..
So after that replacement of all ";" this will became ...,,"ns=2,s=MAIN.test.text,,,.. so the ns=2,s needs to be changed back. Sorry I forgot about that part of the file

PS 3: Don't know how to add files to post so here is a portion of the file.

```
0;0;0;;1;0;0;0;;EQU;NONE;;;;;;;;;;;;;;d;7;1;
;;;;"ns=2;s=MAIN";;;0;;;;;;;;0;;;;0;1;;0;;0;0;0;;1;0;
;;;;"ns=2;s=MAIN";;;0;;;;;;;;0;;;;0;1;;0;;0;0;0;;1;0;
;;;;"ns=2;s=MAIN";;;0;;;;;;;;0;;;;0;1;;0;;0;0;0;;1;0;
;;;;"ns=2;s=MAIN";;;0;;;;;;;;0;;;;0;1;;0;;0;0;0;;1;0;
;;;;"ns=2;s=MAIN.Test.text";;;0;;;;;;;;0;;;;0;1;;0;;0;0;0;;1;0;
```

This is the code I have

```vb
Source_Path = "C:...\Test_xlsx_File.xlsx" 
Set WB_Source = Workbooks.Open(Source_Path)
WB_Source.Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Don't show pop-ups
WB_Source.SaveAs Filename:= _ 
   "C:...\Test_csv_saved.csv" _ 
   ,FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
WB_Source.Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'show pop-ups again
WB_Source.Close (True) 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'set to false above
```

Comment: What is the code you are using for the save as csv .

Comment: Source_Path = "C:...\Test_xlsx_File.xlsx"
Set WB_Source = Workbooks.Open(Source_Path)
WB_Source.Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Don't show pop-ups
WB_Source.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:...\Test_csv_saved.csv" _
    , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
WB_Source.Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'show pop-ups again

WB_Source.Close (True)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'set to false above

Comment: Try `WB_Source.Close False` rather than `WB_Source.Close (True)`

Comment: Is there a reason for that? I thought that the "(True)" is just to make sure that the (csv) file is saved when closing in case the file already exists = overwrite.

Comment: Does the source excel file contain data that are decimal numbers? if so, check if the semicolon-csv uses comma as decimal point. A mass change from ; to , can be troublesome depending on the data.

Comment: The `SaveAs` has an default option `Local:=False` which typically uses US format. The additional `Save` is not needed and could be using the local settings.

Comment: `"ns=2;s=MAIN;` Is that correct with just 1 double quote ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake again. The whole part that doesn't change is between double qoute.
Should be at the start and end. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is simply to write to text file directly.

Below is the edited code. It is assuming that the .xlsx file is closed then the code is run. This will then open the Excel file and when it is opened it also is active then.

```
Sub CreateTxtFile()
Dim pathSrc As String, fNameSrc As String, pathTarg As String, fNameTarg As String, myStr As String
Dim fileNumber As Integer, lr As Integer, lc As Integer, rw As Integer, cl As Integer

lr = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  
pathSrc = "C:\Temp\"
fNameSrc = "Test.xlsx"

Workbooks.Open pathSrc & fNameSrc

pathTarg = "C:\Temp\"
fNameTarg = "OutputTextFile.txt"

fileNumber = FreeFile

Open pathTarg & fNameTarg For Output As fileNumber

For rw = 1 To lr
    lc = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    myStr = ""
    For cl = 1 To lc
        If cl < lc Then
            myStr = myStr & Cells(rw, cl).Value & ","
        Else
            myStr = myStr & Cells(rw, cl).Value
        End If
    Next cl
    Print #fileNumber, myStr
Next rw

Close fileNumber
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mika.
I kind of get what this is doing but the problem is that it's looking at the excel from which I run the macro.  It's taking the top row (header) and it overwrites all the date in "C:...\Test_csv_saved.txt" with it.

Comment: note that the users that has system settings to semicolon as csv separator probably has comma , as decimal point. So if there are any decimals in the data, this might not work.

Comment: True that, thanks tnavidi.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the changes in the file you can use this method:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeTextFile()
    Dim path As String
    Dim textFile As Integer
    Dim ignore As Boolean
    Dim letter
    path = "C:\Temp\test.txt"
    ignore = False
    textFile = FreeFile
    Open path For Binary As textFile
    Do While Not EOF(textFile)
        letter = Input(1, textFile)
        If letter = """" Then ignore = Not ignore
        If letter = ";" And Not ignore Then Put textFile, Loc(textFile), ","
    Loop
    Close textFile
End Sub
```

Alternatively you can force excel to use , comma as separator when saving as csv. Then you don't need to do any changes at all:

```
Sub saveAsCSV()
    Dim path As String
    Dim sep As String
    Dim blah As Boolean
    path = "C:\Temp\Test_csv_saved.csv"
    blah = Application.UseSystemSeparators
    sep = Application.DecimalSeparator
    Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
    Application.Workbooks("book1.xlsm").SaveAs Filename:=path, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = blah
    Application.DecimalSeparator = sep
End Sub
```

You will need to add in the WB source ( i just used the active workbook in my testing)

Comment: I realised that csv will put quotes around the text if any delimiters appears in the cell. Made an "ignore" boolean that will ignore those semicolons

Comment: Note that you don't need to rename the file. you can change the path to your original `"C:...\Test_csv_saved.csv"`

Comment: Another thing i just realised; if you have any text with commas, they need to be wrapped in quotes. And you may need to change decimals from , to .

Comment: Thank you tnavidi,
That work indeed as needed based on my above question. Can I ask you if there is a way that instead of one character to look at a group of characters?
I just realized that in that file there are future cells (once converted back to csv) that need this "ns=2;s" to stay with ";" 
So it will be more like Open file-> replace all ";" with "," -> replace all "ns=2,s" with "ns=2;s" -> Save -> Close file.
Because the file is ~ 19,000 KB the macro freezes for about 40-60 sec. I will add a process bar.

Comment: the `Input(1, textFile)` specifies the 1 byte of reading, you can change this to 6. You may need to seek back to next character by using something like `Seek textFile, loc(textFile) - 5` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Do you mind adding that to your posted code. I tried a few times to add "Seek textFile..."but it's either replacing all ";" or none. I have no idea how to use this function.
Thank you.

Comment: I added a different solution that will force comma as separator when saving as csv. Then you don't need to alter

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateCSV()

    Const SEP = ","
    Const FOLDER = "C:...\"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ar
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    Dim Source_Path As String, CSVfile As String, s As String

    Source_Path = "Test_xlsx_File.xlsx"
    CSVfile = "Test_csv_saved.csv"
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & Source_Path, ReadOnly:=True)
    ar = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    
    Dim fso As Object, ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.createtextfile(FOLDER & CSVfile)
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(ar)
        s = ""
        For c = 1 To UBound(ar, 2)
            If c > 1 Then s = s & SEP
            If IsNumeric(ar(r, c)) Then
                s = s & ar(r, c)
            Else
                s = s & """" & ar(r, c) & """"
            End If
        Next
        ts.writeline s
        n = n + 1
    Next
    ts.Close
    wb.Close
    MsgBox n & " lines written to " & FOLDER & CSVfile, vbInformation
    
End Sub
```